# UITableView static cells not adjusting to screen size

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Im having trouble resizing content inside static cells to fit different iPhone screen sizes. 
Looking at the image below you can see that the UIPickerView and Sign In UILabel both did not resize in width. 
I've tried adding code to the ViewDidLoad like so

`self.signUp.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.signUp.frame.size.height);`to programmatically adjust their sizes but nothing changed.

I also tried adding equal width constraints to make it match the UITableViewCell contentView width and that did nothing as well.

Same issues happens to all UILabels (Membership,Schedule,Method...) and UITextFields (Comments)
This is all occurring in a UITableViewController.

How can I get it to resize?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apples freeform UIViewController and UITableView are externally useful in this circumstance. 
If you design your app in the storyboard, before applying constraints make sure the UIViewController's size is freeform (big square that doesn't match any screen size). 
Then add constrains. 
When you run the app, the app will resize properly.